# ¿Que evento del DataGridView utilizar para actualizar base de datos después de una edición?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Tengo un `DataSet` del cual obtengo los datos para el `DataGridView` y utilizo las funciones del `adapter.Fill()` y `adapter.Update()` para actualizar la base de datos. También utilizo el evento `dgv_CellEndEdit()` para comprobar los cambios pero este no me reconoce los cambios para el Update.

> Aquí el código...

### Actualizo el DataGridView.

```
private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.defaultProyectosTableAdapter.Fill(this.connection_Manager.DefaultProyectos);
}
```

---

### Actualizo base de datos.

```
private void dgvCBD_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    //Verifico los datos antes de actualizar.
    if (TextFilter(dgvCBD[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString()))
    {
        //Actualizo la base de datos
        this.defaultProyectosTableAdapter.Update(this.connection_Manager.DefaultProyectos);
        Form_Load(null, null); //No aparecen los cambios
    }
    else
    {
        dgvCBD.CancelEdit();
        MessageBox.Show("Proyecto ya existe.");
    }
}
```

---

El problema es que la base de datos no se actualiza al menos que realice el `Update()` en un botón.

### Codigo del botón.

```
private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Actualizo la base de datos
    this.defaultProyectosTableAdapter.Update(this.connection_Manager.DefaultProyectos);
    Form_Load(null, null); //Aparecen los cambios
}
```

---

**Simplemente** me gustaría que la base de datos se actualice automáticamente utilizando un evento del `DataGridView` al terminar de editar una celda si es posible de lo contrario me gustaria saber cual es la mejor forma de hacerlo.

**NOTA:** He intentado sin éxito con los siguientes eventos

- KeyPess events (Todos)
- CellValueChanged
- CellLeave
- CellParsing
- CellValidating
- CellValidated
- entre otro...

Comment: Que tiene el boton update? hay alguna diferencia?

Comment: @gbianchi ya puse el código del botón.

Comment: Al parecer el problema es que si intento actualizar la base de datos en el evento `CellEditEnd()` los cambios aun no han sido guardados en el `DataGridView` y por eso el comando `Update()` no funciona.

Comment: Si, creo que debes utilizar UpdateData() o cellEndEdit() en el DataGridView para que acepte los cambios.

Comment: @Mean24 con ese mismo no me funciona.

Answer (score 2):

Yo uso el **SaveChanges();** para guardar los registros modificados desde un DatagridView usando un Stored Procedure a la base datos. Tecnología implementada Entity Framework.

```
private void dgvPersonal_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            var SeleccionDelGrid = new nomina();

        SeleccionDelGrid.cedula = Convert.ToString(dgvPersonal.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value);
        SeleccionDelGrid.nombres= Convert.ToString(dgvPersonal.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value);
        SeleccionDelGrid.apellidos = Convert.ToString(dgvPersonal.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value);
        SeleccionDelGrid.cargo = Convert.ToString(dgvPersonal.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value);
        SeleccionDelGrid.departamento = Convert.ToString(dgvPersonal.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value);
        SeleccionDelGrid.salario = Convert.ToDecimal(dgvPersonal.CurrentRow.Cells[5].Value);

        empresaEntities1 _empleados = new empresaEntities1();

        var CedulaCapturada = _empleados.UpdateEmpleado(Convert.ToString(SeleccionDelGrid.cedula), SeleccionDelGrid.nombres, SeleccionDelGrid.apellidos, SeleccionDelGrid.cargo, SeleccionDelGrid.departamento, SeleccionDelGrid.salario, SeleccionDelGrid.UrlFoto);

        _empleados.SaveChanges();

        MessageBox.Show("Se ha modificado el trabajador en base de datos", "¡Información!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

        CargarGrid();
    }
```

Espero sirva de ayuda para una pronta visita a esta pregunta.

Comment: Hace tiempo que hice esta pregunta, lo pude solucionar con el evento `CellValidated()`.